# Remove "Fetching Data.." message when scroll in a JSF table

Tags: jsf, view, fetch, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a table which rows are populated programatically, not based on a query. In other words there is not an entity which is connected with the view object responsible for the table. The table is located in a resizeable pop-up. If I scroll down the rows of the table I see the message "Fetching Data..". My question is is there is a way this message to be removed - all rows to be fetched at once.
The things I tried were to set range size both of the view and iterator to -1 which is supposed to retrieve all rows, but it does not work. Any ideas why?

Table in JSF page:

```
     <af:table fetchSize="#{bindings.ABC.rangeSize}"
               id="t2">
```

Iterator range size:

[image]

View object range size:

[image]

Is it the correct approach of a solution? If not, which one is the right? Thanks!

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question accordingly

Comment: How many rows ARE retrieved? Some default value you can find in 'google'? Might be that the DB limits things... It is oracle you know ;-)

Comment: I have already checked that the default value is 25. I use -1 in order to override it. In the table background I use view object which rows are populated programatically, not based on a query. So, I think that there is not a database operation?

Comment: All rows are retrieved after I scroll down the table, but I see the “Fetching Data..” . Is it possible not to see it?

Comment: I tried to set to fetchSize a large number, for example 10000 and when scroll down the fetching message disappears, but my idea is this value to be set to the size of the rows in the view object. (-1 for all rows but it does not work as I have done it in this way)

Comment: I understand the issue, but if it never the less defaults to 25 if you put in -1 then something else is overriding the -1. Sorry, but I'm no ADF user so cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set contentDelivery="immediate"